# How to save an uploaded file on localhost?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, localhost

I have been using to upload an image file from HTML5/JS and using PHP script to save it in localhost(/var/www/) but i cant save it. the function move_uploaded_file always returns false while there is exists an object in _FILES object. I am a newbie in php:

```
  $target = "upload/";
  if(!empty($_FILES))
  {
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
     {
     echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['image_file']['name']). " has been uploaded...";
     } 
     else {
     echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file. {$error}";
     }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "_files is empty";
  }
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting!

Comment: Problem is in second parameter of move_uploaded_file - see my answer

Comment: Could have read the docs on move_uploaded_file... :)

Comment: @Corbin: Yes corbin, i have read its documentation and i was thinking that perhaps i am not been able to make a proper HTTP request in JS file but it was correct. There may be some error with the parameters that i have been passing to it

Comment: where your upload folder exists and from where you are running the upload code?

Comment: my code folder is in /var/www/example/ and my upload folder is also in /example folder @punit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $target.$_FILES['image_file']['name'])
```

Because you need to specify the name of file, not only the directory.

See example from [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I hope that the problem should have been solved but its still there, i have changed my code according to your answer but i cant see the file in my upload folder.
any more suggesions??

Comment: Changed the code, please see if it works now (tmp_name to name)

Comment: still its same, when i print the name or size of file via _FILES['image_file']['name'] it shows me the correct name which means i am getting the file object at my php page.

Comment: when i use the above documentation code then echo some message inside the loop, it didnt show up which means loop didnt iterate even for once. Any more help plz

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'])) 
     {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $target.$_FILES['image_file']['name']);
     echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['image_file']['name']). " has been uploaded...";
     }
```