# How to save file to server after checking for validation with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

If a user uploads a file and the contents are retrieved like so

```
$file = $_FILES['uploadedFile'];
```

Then, the file is sent to a function to make sure it's an accepted file type. If it is, save it on the server

```
function saveInputFile($file){
   if($check->checkFile($file)== TRUE){
      //save $file on my server
   }
   else{
      echo "can't be saved!";
   }
}
```

**Assuming it passes the checkFile function, how can I then save this file to my server from within the saveInputFile function? Can I set the file equal to a variable, and then save that variable or do I have to save the file directly from the POST data?**

I've seen it done like this, but I already have the file passed into this function.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
   echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
 } else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

When it comes down to it, I want to save a file in the following function. Can I pass the file like a variable as I did in the saveInputFile function above, or does it not work like this?

Comment: And you haven't checked the PHP manual for this? There are like 1 million tutorials on google on how to save an uploaded file? Event 3 seconds to use the SO search gave me this duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545068/how-to-save-an-uploaded-file-on-localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545068/how-to-save-an-uploaded-file-on-localhost)

Comment: @dbf You don't understand my question. I'm asking if I can obtain the posted file, set it equal to a variable, and then save the file via that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the upload file a type of it's own that has the methods it needs next to it's data. That will make the usage more flexible:

```
$upload = new UploadFile($_FILES['uploadedFile']);
$message = saveInputFile($upload);
echo $message;

function saveInputFile(UploadFile $upload)
{
    if ($check->checkFile($upload->getBasename()) == TRUE) {
        $message = $upload->moveTo($target_path)
            ? sprintf('The file %s has been uploaded', $upload->getBasename())
            : 'There was an error uploading the file, please try again!'
            ;
    } else {
        $message = "can't be saved!";
    }

    return $message;
}
```

The new type `UploadFile` represents one file from the the `$_FILE` array, it is a class that wraps the basic data and methods a file-upload carries. Here is some example code:

```
class UploadFile
{
    protected $file;

    private $filename;

    public function __construct(array $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function hasError()
    {
        return $this->getProperty('error') !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK;
    }

    public function getError()
    {
        return $this->getProperty('error');
    }

    public function getBasename()
    {
        return basename($this->getProperty('name'));
    }

    public function getFilename()
    {
        return $this->filename;
    }

    /**
     * @param $newName
     * @return NULL|SplFileInfo
     * @throws BadMethodCallException
     */
    public function moveTo($newName)
    {
        $newName  = (string)$newName;
        $filename = $this->getFilename();

        if ($filename !== NULL) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf('Upload file (%s) has been already moved (%s).', $this->getBasename(), $filename));
        }

        $tmpName = $this->getProperty('tmp_name');

        if (move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $newName)) {
            $this->filename = realpath($newName);
        }

        return $this->getFileInfo();
    }

    /**
     * @return SplFileInfo|NULL
     */
    public function getFileInfo()
    {
        $filename = $this->getFilename();

        if ($filename !== NULL) {
            return new SplFileInfo($filename);
        }
    }

    protected function getProperty($name, $default = NULL)
    {
        if (isset($this->file[$name])) {
            return $this->file[$name];
        }

        return $default;
    }
}
```

Use it at your will. See as well [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/SplFileInfo) and the [documentation about file uploads in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) which documents the structure of the `$_FILE` array and the [PHP upload error codes (which are important)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: A more basic variant would be passing the array, however and array does not have any type, it's just array, an object can have a concrete type and that is helpful. And glad it helped, the code is not really tested, so I hope this works well for you. Also if you use an array of file input elements, this does not work out of the box because the format of the `$_FILES` array changes. A good class should deal with that, you might want to extend from it and make the `getProperty` function protected before that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `move_uploaded_file` function should take 2 parameters, the *source file name* and the `destination file` name.

In PHP the file move function is called [rename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php).

Comment: What I'm asking is if I can set a variable as the file, then use a function to save the file to the server via the variable.

Comment: You write: $file = $_FILES['uploadedFile']; You should write: `$filename = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: @JvdBerg, Once I set $filename according to what you suggested, can I then use $filename in with move_uploaded_file?

Comment: Yes, use it as yoyr source file name