# Uploading photo in Php

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I've been trying to do a photo upload using Php. What I am seeing when I do a submit is, the page keeps loading infinitely.

End result the photo is not being uploaded to the directory.

Here is the HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Photo Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Php Script :

```
    <style>
    .sucess{
        color:#088A08;
    }
    .error{
        color:red;
    }
</style>

<?php
$file_exts = array("jpg", "bmp", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$upload_exts = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
    && in_array($upload_exts, $file_exts))
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
// Enter your path to upload file here
        if (file_exists("uploads/" .
            $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            echo "<div class='error'>"."(".$_FILES["file"]["name"].")".
                " already exists. "."</div>";
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "<div class='sucess'>"."Stored in: " .
                "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]."</div>";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<div class='error'>Invalid file</div>";
}
?>
```

I've taken this code sample from [Here](http://www.infotuts.com/image-file-upload-script-php/).

I cannot understand what is going wrong here, but I think it has something to do with the path, but I am not sure.

Some help will be appreciated.

*I've edited the code and changed it to 'uploads/' .
It now works!

Comment: It might be because your `paths` all start with `c:\\`. Don't think yu can do that. You need to use an actual server to upload to.

Comment: If you check the link I attached, it also contains the same. Am I going wrong there ?

Comment: They use `wamp`. Do you have a localhost installed?

Comment: Yes, I am using XAMPP

Comment: Is your directory writable? What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: Yes, it is. I donot get any error. The page simply keeps loading infinitely after I click Submit.

Comment: make sure that php has permissions to the folder you're writing to, and add is_dir and is_writable before move_uploaded_file to verify that php can access that dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked it out use Relative Path Instead of absolute path then there will be no problem which ever environment you are working in local or server

eg:Instead of this C:\Users\Priyabrata\PhpstormProjects\FileUpload/uploads/

Use uploads/

It will work

when you host it on server some hosting providers will not provide the access so you have to change the folder permissions to writable and it will work cheers

Answer (score 1):

See you are reffering like `C:\\Users\\Priyabrata\\PhpstormProjects\\FileUpload/uploads/`.Maybe this leads to the problem.

Replace it with the actual server link you use ..

Comment: I wanted to test it in my local machine before uploading to the server. Any way of doing that ?

Comment: @Priyabrata then you can choose the localhost directory ..please refer this ..you wil get it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545068/how-to-save-an-uploaded-file-on-localhost

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and it works fine for me (I used different path since I am on Ubuntu). Try specifying your path without double slashes. (Like in the sample link you provided). Also make sure the folder exists ;)

Comment: In php storm, if double '\' is not used, then the slashes wont be considered at-all. Thats the problem I'am facing.